# How to reference a JavaScript file in Lib from an HTML file in Data?

Tags: firefox-addon, directory-structure, firefox-addon-sdk

I decided to give [Mozilla's Add-on Builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org) a try. My directory structure looks something like this:

[image]

The problem is that the file `popup.html` needs to reference `stackapi.js`. But I have absolutely no clue how to do that. Looking through the Mozilla docs, there seems to be a way to do the opposite:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var url_of_popup = data.url("popup.html");
```

This allows scripts in Lib to access data files in Data. But I need to do the opposite.

Comment: Does `../Lib/what-have-you.js` not work?

Comment: @JonPurdy: No, that does not work. Apparently `popup.html` is in the root directory.

Answer (score 3):

In add-ons built with the Add-on SDK (and the Builder is merely a web interface for the SDK) web pages cannot access extension modules directly - they don't have the necessary privileges. If you simply need to include a JavaScript file from the web page then you should put that file into the `data` directory. However, it won't have any special privileges then (like being able to call `require()`).

You don't tell how you are using `popup.html` but I guess that it is a [panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html). If you want that page to communicate with your add-on you need to use content scripts. Put a content script file into the `data` directory, assign it to your panel via `contentScriptFile` parameter. See [documentation on content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html), the content script will be able to use `self.postMessage()` to send messages to the extension, the extension can perform the necessary operations and send a message back then.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the url of the `stackapi.js` file by navigating up from the `/data` folder and back down the `/lib` folder like so:

```
var url=require("sdk/self").data.url("../lib/stackapi.js");
```

Then use that resource url in the `contentScriptFile` parameter when attaching scripts to what I assume is going to be `popup.html`.

You'll need to check which environment you're currently in to determine if you need to add any references to the `exports` object to make them accessible from within the addon.

```
if(typeof(exports)!="undefined"){
  exports.something=function(){...};
}
```

Comment: As of Firefox 31, this hack appears to work only when FF is launched from SDK's cfx. Once the add-on is packaged into an xpi, FF is unable to find those libraries moved from '/data' to '/lib'.

Answer (score 0):

Had to go through the same scenario, but solution by jongo45 does not seem to work anymore. Somehow found a solution which worked for me. Posting below as it might help someone in need.

Below code obtains list of all files under "lib/subdir".

```
const fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");    
const fspath = require("sdk/fs/path");
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

const currDir = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIDirectoryServiceProvider)
            .getFile("CurWorkD", {}).path;

const listOfFiles = fileIO.list(fspath.resolve(currDir,'lib/subdir'));
```