# Using the same file in add-on and content

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a script that I want to use on both sides, the add-on side and the content side. The problem is that content and add-on scripts reside in different folders (data and lib respectively).

How can I access a data script from lib or vice versa?

Comment: I thik you are architect problem. Want you want to do specifically?

Comment: I'm porting a chrome extension. I have a script that I use in both add-on and content side. I don't want to edit it in two places every time, I want to include it from the same place twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost the same question asked in [How to reference a JavaScript file in Lib from an HTML file in Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706976/how-to-reference-a-javascript-file-in-lib-from-an-html-file-in-data), so I'll just rephrase the answer I gave over there.

Put the file in the `/lib/` folder then get the file's resouce url via:

```
var url=require("sdk/self").data.url("../lib/shared-file.js");
```

Once you have this url you can attach it to a tab or popup via the `contentScriptFile` parameter.

Note:  You'll need to check which environment you're currently in to determine if you need to add any references to the `exports` object to make them accessible from within the addon.

```
if(typeof(exports)!="undefined"){
  exports.something=function(){...};
}
```

Comment: It's so easy, I'm impressed!

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is most probably not possible. Even if it is, given the meticulous separation of addon and content code, it would require a load of ugly hacks.

But depending on what your code does (number crunching?) perhaps you could utilize Workers.